# Fixed point of the polylogarithm

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

Is there a neat closed-form expression for the real fixed point of the polylogarithm for non-integer order $\alpha$ and real $s \in (0,1)$? More specifically, I'm looking for an expression for the point $s \in (0,1)$ such that:

$$ f(s) := \frac{\textrm{Li}_{\alpha}(s)}{\zeta(\alpha)} = s, \quad \alpha \in (1,2) \textrm{ and } s \in (0,1) $$

where the polylogarithm $\textrm{Li}_{\alpha}$ is defined as:

$$ \textrm{Li}_{\alpha}(s) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{s^n}{n^{\alpha}} $$

I just normalized by $\zeta(\alpha)$ so that $f(1) = 1$. I don't know much complex analysis so, outside of a lot of messy algebraic manipulations, I'm pretty much stuck.

Comment: zeta can be extended to a  function when $\alpha \in (0,1)$ and same with  Li_{\alpha} so it seems to me like you have your fixed point  f(1)=1